# how to dynamically enable a disabled ion-tab? Ionic-v4

Tags: javascript, ionic4

What is the best strategy to enable and disable ion tabs?

Comment: You're reciving a lot of downvotes due to the fact that stackoverflow isn't a free code machine. You should provide some code that you have already tried. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Synapsis I think this wasn't a bad question regardless of the lack of 'code'.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the disabled property on `ion-tab-button`:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tab-button#properties

If you want to control that dynamically then you can put a `[]` around it:

```
<ion-tab-button tab="schedule" [disabled]="isButtonDisabled">
  <ion-icon name="calendar"></ion-icon>
  <ion-label>Schedule</ion-label>
</ion-tab-button>
```

and then set `isButtonDisabled` to true or false.